# Gradle Custom String Notation in dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm creating a global repository for all the artifacts that I'm producing. Right now I've created an S3 bucket as repository where I'm storing the artifacts.

As there is no group (artifacts are global), I ended up duplicating the name as the group so the current notation for a dependency is `Name:Name:Version`. For this, I've created an extension function that takes two arguments, a name (the dependency that I want to add to the project) and the version.

For example, I would add `implementation("Name", "1.0")` if I wanted the dependency `Name` in my project. This is translated to `implementation("Name:Name:1.0")` and works fine but I feel that it is a little bit ugly and can be confusing, the dependency in the `External Libraries` tree in IntelliJ shows the dependency as `Gradle: Name:Name:1.0`, the longer the name is, the uglier it is.

The question is, is it possible to write a custom Notation that let me just do `implementation("Name", "1.0")` without an extension function so it only shows `Gradle: Name:1.0` and everything else is handled in the background?

I have looked at the class `ParsedModuleStringNotation` and it seems the thing that I would need to change (create my own), but the creation of the objects is hardcoded, I am unsure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare S3 repository as flatDir - there is an option for what you are asking
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html

flatDir(args)

Adds a resolver that looks into a number of directories for artifacts. The artifacts are expected to be located in the root of the specified directories. The resolver ignores any group/organization information specified in the dependency section of your build script. If you only use this kind of resolver you might specify your dependencies like ":junit:4.4" instead of "junit:junit:4.4".

was able to work as below

```
repositories {
    def s = project.rootDir.toString() + "/lib/"
    flatDir dirs: s
    mavenCentral()
}

//compileOnly 'javax.jms:jms-api:1.1-rev-1'
compileOnly ':my-jms:1.2'
```

Comment: That looks promising, if I could combine maven and flatDir it would be ideal. I'll look into the possibility of creating my own repository handler!

Comment: It might be trickier than it seems: if even possible at all https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1400